# PHP usort with missing values

Tags: php, usort

How can I manipulate the usort function here to move objects missing a LastUse key to the bottom?

Short of have another loop prior to this that sets LastUse as a 0 value, I'm not entirely sure the best way to achieve it.

I'd be looking to the sorted LastUse values at the top of the list, and those that do not have a value at the bottom of the list.

```
    usort($trackdata, function ($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($b->LastUse) - strtotime($a->LastUse);
    });
```

Comment: What does "ignore" exactly mean, given you're reordering the elements?

Comment: What is the data being sorted?

Comment: Depending on whether you want the elements with missing values to appear at the end or the beginning of the list, just have a case in the function to return 1 or -1 when the value is missing.

Comment: "Ignore" isn't a valid answer to the question *"is `a` greater than, equal to or smaller than `b`?"*

Comment: I think, he means with ignore, when ($b->LastUse === null or empty)

Comment: Re-worded! 

How can I manipulate the usort function here to move objects missing a LastUse key to the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
   usort($trackdata, function ($a, $b) {
        if (empty($a->LastUse) && empty($b->LastUse)) return 0;
        if (empty($a->LastUse)) return -1;
        if (empty($b->LastUse)) return 1;
        return strtotime($b->LastUse) - strtotime($a->LastUse);
    });
```

Didn't test it so if they swimp up to the top move minus sign from first row to second to change their position.

Comment: You should also consider the case where both `$a` and `$b` have an *empty* `LastUse` (→ `return 0`).

Comment: A negative value (`-1`, f.e.) returned by the callback comparison function says that `$a` should stay in front of `$b` in the sorted list. The first `if` should `return +1;`, the second one should `return -1;`.

Comment: This did it. Thank you for your assistance!

https://pastebin.com/ymuQ57Qu

Comment: @Scott That condition for *both empty* needs to come first, and must result in `0` (both values are equal)!

Comment: Updated my answer, even don't think it's necessary. Those items without LastUse doesn't have to be ordered.

Comment: Your callback needs to return *consistent* results back to `usort`. If two elements are actually equal (no preferred order), but your callback says one is actually larger, especially if that same callback might return the opposite response when the elements are reversed, that can negatively influence the sorting algorithm. The result will probably still be correct, but the sorting may be less efficient.